# One assert statement tests several conditions

Tags: java, unit-testing, integration-testing

I found many information about bad practices to use several asserts in one method (one test condition). It's clear. Each method should test one and only one condition. So it should be one assert in most cases.

But I can't find any information about best practices to situation, if my **one** assert tests several conditions.

Example:

```
@Test
public void findAllPerformers_returnsPerformersInAlphabeticalOrder() {
    List<String> performers = reportRepository.findAllPerformers();
    assertThat("Should return performers in alphabetical order",
            performers, contains("Bart Simpson", "Homer Simpson",
                    "Ned Flanders", "Xena Warrior Princess"));
}
```

First, I had to have 2 more test methods (conditions): `findAllPerformers_returnsAllUniquePerformers` and `findAllPerformers_returnsEachPerformerOnlyOnce`. But then I realized that my first method tests this two conditions too!

So, what should I do?

1. Leave all methods as is.
2. Remove 2 other test methods and rename my `findAllPerformers_returnsPerformersInAlphabeticalOrder` method to very long name with all three conditions included (because it really tests all three conditions!)
3. Just remove 2 other test methods.
4. Leave all methods but invoke `findAllPerformers_returnsPerformersInAlphabeticalOrder` method from two other methods.
5. Copy-paste `findAllPerformers_returnsPerformersInAlphabeticalOrder` method contents to two other methods.
6. Anything else...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with a unit test which tests more than one piece of functionality, provided that you _also_ test each piece of functionality separately.

Comment: So, you suggest "1. Leave all methods as is."?

Comment: One assert should test one condition. Otherwise you can't tell which one failed. However I don't see why one method can't test several conditions with several asserts, if they are related.

Comment: I can't really comment further because you gave us zero functionality.

Comment: Your example looks more like [BDD](http://jbehave.org/introduction.html) than it does an unit test.

Comment: I don't understand how can I clarify the question more. My first test method, which should test only that `findAllPerformers` returns performers in alphabetical order, *by accident* tests also that `findAllPerformers` returns each performers only once. But for the second condition I already have another dedicated test method. So should I delete this another method because first method already tests both conditions (although accidentally), or should I leave both methods and not to worry about CPU doing useless work?

Comment: You don't need to worry about the CPU in a test. I would put the first test last.

Comment: Ok, thanks you all. So, if any test method accidentally tests conditions of another test methods (while still tests some unique condition) - it's ok.
I'll try to comprehend this information. :)

Answer (score 0):

If this test fails then the person looking at the failed test would initially see `findAllPerformers_returnsPerformersInAlphabeticalOrder()`.
Looking at that alone it appears that the method under test returned a list that wasn't in alphabetical order, not that the list didn't contain 'Bart Simpson'.

Avoid options 4 and 5, they don't really solve anything and will increase duplication/maintenance without any added value (since tests will fail for reasons not mentioned in the test name). Instead try to find a way to actually test what you want with the assert.